# I can connect to localhost at emulator but not on real device

Tags: php, android, localhost, wamp

I really made research about this issue but nothing works for me. I am using WampServer and have a php webservice.

I wrote an app on Android Studio. I have a `login.php` at localhost. On android emulator I use `10.0.2.2:8080/login.php` and everything works perfect. But on real device,it is not working. I tried

`127.0.0.1:8080` (localhost)
`192.168.2.1:8080` (default gateway)
`192.168.2.60:8080` (IPv4 adress).

Nothing is working, what should I do? I hope somebody knows the answer

Thank you in advance

Comment: How are you running a Wamp server on android? Because on the emulator you are connecting to an ipaddress and port. Localhost would mean running the server on the same device as the one requesting data

Comment: Use the IP of your PC/ Laptop for using on real device & make sure that your PC/ Laptop use same connection with your device

Comment: I am not running server on device. Server is on laptop. I wrote an app and it can go to login.php and do the stuff on emulator. But when I use this app on real device. It doesn't login.

Comment: `It doesn't login`. Very bad problem description. Like `its not working`. Please take some more effort to tell us what happens instead. Which errors/exceptions do you see in the logcat?

Comment: Try the url from a browser on your device.

Comment: I tried with device browser and it looks like 192.168.2.60 (IPv4)  works. But in application,still it is not working @greenapps I cannot show any error because I don't get any.

Comment: Of course there will be errors and exception then. But as you neglect them and do nothing with them you and the user dont know.

Comment: So then now you know what you have to do! Or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did suffer from the same problem from past 2 days, but I ultimately found the fix:
1)
Change the entry in httpd.conf:

```
#onlineoffline tag – don’t remove
Require local
```

to

```
#onlineoffline tag – don’t remove
Require all granted
```

Source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XbBGYm14xY4

2) Change the entry in httpd-vhosts.conf:

```
<Directory “c:/wamp64/www/”>
Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
AllowOverride All
Require local
</Directory>
```

to

```
<Directory “c:/wamp64/www/”>
Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WzD_J9vSF0E

Answer (score 0):

You should connect to local IP of your PC (you can check with `ipconfig`/`ifconfig`).

I guess that is `192.168.2.60:8080` you wrote. Then make sure you are on same network and that port `8080` on your PC is open.

Comment: I tried that ip but no luck. The devices are on the same network(my home)

Comment: Maybe the firewall is blocking you -> disable firewall on your pc and try it again.

Comment: I disabled firewall but still not working. On emulator 8080 port is working. But on device I tried everything but no luck. I am really in deep

Comment: Ok, that's interesting. You can test connection in browser, e.g. you can make any request to your server: `localhost:8080/whatever-goes-here` from your pc browser just like you do within app. You should see some response (200 or 400 code). If that worked, go from your device browser to `192.168.2.60:8080/whatever-goes-here` (do the ipconfig to make sure address didn't change) and check the connection. This way we can eliminate that your app isn't problem.